# unity collision doesnt work, what is the problem in my code?

Tags: unity-game-engine

im trying to track collsion on a unity project and i dont get whats wrong
thats the code i'm working with.
im trying to destroy an object on collision but it doesnt work for some reason.

```
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
        if (col.collider.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
        {
            Destroy(col.gameObject);
            Debug.Log("collided");
        }
    }
```

it hits the object but nothing happends i dont get a message and the object doesnt get destroyed

Comment: Is it tagged correctly? And just to be sure do both objects have colliders on them? Are they both **not** `isTrigger`? Does at least one object have a `Rigidbody` component and how exactly are you moving the object(s)?

Comment: The bullet has rigid body and capsule  colider. The second object has a shpere  colder , none of the has is trigger. And I move it with velocity 0,0,speed

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the script you posted is a component of some kind of a character (which it should be since you are looking for an Enemy using its tag) and you have proper Rigidbody components with proper settings and Colliders, you should use:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    // You can also use col.gameObject.tag == "Enemy" since it does the same thing as CompareTag().
    // Although using col.gameObject.tag == "Enemy" is less performant.
    if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))
    {
        // Using print to get proper information on what is happening.
        print("destroyed " + col.gameObject.name);
        // Destroying the gameObject with the tag "Enemy"
        Destroy(col.gameObject);
    }
}
```

If you wanted to destroy the player object then you should change the tag accordingly and have this script as a component of the enemy.

Answer (score 0):

The most common issues if nothing is showing up can be:

1. the object has no RigidBody (or RigidBody2D if you are in a 2D project) component
2. the 2 objects are in 2 layers which don't collide with others (or the same layer which don't collide with itself). Check both objects' layers, and go to Edit -> Project Settings -> Physics (or Physics2D if the project is in 2D) and go at the bottom and check that the layers collide with each other (the check box is on)
3. one of the 2 colliders is in 2D and the other in 3D

Answer (score 0):

If you've setup your Collider as a Trigger then you need to use OnTriggerEnter instead of OnCollisionEnter.